# Line chart is not showing and is considered as a part of the column data

Tags: json, charts, highcharts

I'm very new to HighCharts and I've decided to use it this summer to make some charts. 
As mentionned in the title, I want to make a combination chart with stacked columns and line (or spline). 
The problem is that I'm not able to show my line chart. I've tried a lot of things but I always end up showing only a line charts with all the data or only stacked columns with all the data again.

Could anyone help me please ?

Here is my code :

test.php

```
    <?php

$cakeDescription = " ";
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title><?php echo $cakeDescription ?></title>
        <link href="webroot/css/cake.generic.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'column'
                        //zoomType: 'xy'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: ' '
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: []
                    },
                    yAxis: [{
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Percentage (%)'
                        },
                        stackLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            style: {
                                fontWeight: 'bold',
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                            }
                        }
                    },{
                        min: 0, 
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                                value: 0,
                                width: 1,
                                color: '#808080'
                            }], 
                        opposite: true
                    }],                         
                    legend: {
                        align: 'right',
                        x: -30,
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        y: 25,
                        floating: true,
                        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
                        borderColor: '#CCC',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        shadow: false
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                                this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + ' %<br/>' +
                                'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal + ' %';
                        }
                        //shared: true
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            stacking: 'normal',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                                style: {
                                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [
                        {type: 'column', 
                        // stacking: 'normal',
                        tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                        }
                        ,yAxis: 0
                        },
                        {type: 'column', 
                         //stacking: 'normal',
                        tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                        }
                        ,yAxis: 0
                        },
                        {type: 'column', 
                        // stacking: 'normal',
                        tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                        }
                        ,yAxis: 0
                        },
                        {type: 'column', 
                        // stacking: 'normal',
                        tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                        }
                        ,yAxis: 0
                        },
                        {type: 'column', 
                        // stacking: 'normal',
                        tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                        }
                        ,yAxis: 0
                        },
                        {type: 'column',
                         //stacking: 'normal',
                        tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                        }
                        ,yAxis: 0
                        },
                        {type: 'column', 
                        // stacking: 'normal',
                        tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                        }
                        ,yAxis: 0
                        },
                        {type: 'column', 
                         //stacking: 'normal',
                        tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                        }
                        ,yAxis: 0
                        },
                        {type: 'column', 
                        // stacking: 'normal',
                        tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                        }
                        ,yAxis: 0
                        },
                        {type: 'column', 
                        // stacking: 'normal',
                        tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                        }
                        ,yAxis: 0
                        },
                        {type: 'column',
                        // stacking: 'normal',
                        tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                        }
                        ,yAxis: 0
                        },
                        {type: 'column', 
                        // stacking: 'normal',
                        tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                        }
                        ,yAxis: 0
                        },
                        {type: 'column', 
                        // stacking: 'normal',
                        tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                        }
                        ,yAxis: 0
                        }, 
                        {type: 'column', 
                        // stacking: 'normal',
                        tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                        }
                        ,yAxis: 0
                        }, 
                        {type: 'line',
                        //stacking: null,
                        tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                        }
                        ,yAxis: 1
                        } 
                    ]
                };
                $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
                    options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data']; //xAxis: {categories: []}
                    options.series[0] = json[1];
                    options.series[1] = json[2];    
                    options.series[2] = json[3];    
                    options.series[3] = json[4];    
                    options.series[4] = json[5];    
                    options.series[5] = json[6];    
                    options.series[6] = json[7];    
                    options.series[7] = json[8];    
                    options.series[8] = json[9];    
                    options.series[9] = json[10];   
                    options.series[10] = json[11];  
                    options.series[11] = json[12];  
                    options.series[12] = json[13];  
                    options.series[13] = json[14]; 
                    options.series[14] = json[15];
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
            }); 

        </script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

When I put zoomType: 'xy' instead of type: 'column in chart: { ... } it shows all the data as a line chart. 
I guess I'm close to my purpose but I really can't see where did I go wrong or what should I add?

My JSON looks something like that by the way :

```json
[{"name":"Period_start_time","data":["2015-08-03","2015-08-01","2015-08-02","2015-08-03","2015-08-04","2015-08-05","2015-08-07","2015-08-08","2015-08-09","2015-08-10"]},{"name":"dcr_34","data":[28.1,35.98,39.01,28.1,29.18,32.13,37.4,34.44,26.48,35.11]},{"name":"dcr_35","data":[55.79,48.86,43.96,55.79,55.25,51.81,45.28,47.78,35.97,52.89]},{"name":"dcr_36","data":[0,0.76,0.31,0,0,1.61,0,0.56,0.4,0]},{"name":"dcr_37","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"dcr_38","data":[14.46,14.02,10.53,14.46,13.23,12.85,15.75,14.44,11.46,12]},{"name":"dcr_39","data":[0.41,0,0,0.41,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"dcr_40","data":[0,0,0.93,0,0.78,0.4,1.18,1.67,0.79,0]},{"name":"dcr_41","data":[1.24,0.38,0.93,1.24,1.56,0,0.39,0,0.4,0]},{"name":"dcr_42","data":[0,0,4.33,0,0,1.2,0,1.11,24.51,0]},{"name":"dcr_43","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"dcr_44","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"dcr_45","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"dcr_46","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"dcr_47","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"dcr_4g","data":[0.8,0.84,1.18,0.8,0.82,0.85,0.82,0.59,0.97,0.8]}]
```

Thank you in advance !

**EDIT** 
data.php

```
<?php

try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}


$sql=<<<SQL
        SELECT `Period_start_time`, `Segment_Name`, `dcr_34`, `dcr_35`, `dcr_36`, 
        `dcr_37`, `dcr_38`, `dcr_39`, `dcr_40`, `dcr_41`, `dcr_42`, `dcr_43`, `dcr_44`, 
        `dcr_45`, `dcr_46`, `dcr_47`, `dcr_4g`
        FROM `drop` 
        WHERE `Segment_Name`='EX'
SQL;

$reponse = $bdd->query($sql); 

$bln = array(); 
$bln['name'] = 'Period_start_time'; 
$rows1['name']='dcr_34'; 
$rows2['name']='dcr_35'; 
$rows3['name']='dcr_36'; 
$rows4['name']='dcr_37'; 
$rows5['name']='dcr_38'; 
$rows6['name']='dcr_39'; 
$rows7['name']='dcr_40'; 
$rows8['name']='dcr_41'; 
$rows9['name']='dcr_42'; 
$rows10['name']='dcr_43'; 
$rows11['name']='dcr_44'; 
$rows12['name']='dcr_45'; 
$rows13['name']='dcr_46'; 
$rows14['name']='dcr_47'; 
$rows15['name']='dcr_4g';


while($donnee=$reponse->fetch()){ 

    $bln['data'][] = $donnee['Period_start_time'];
    $rows1['data'][] = $donnee['dcr_34'];
    $rows2['data'][] = $donnee['dcr_35'];           
    $rows3['data'][] = $donnee['dcr_36'];           
    $rows4['data'][] = $donnee['dcr_37'];           
    $rows5['data'][] = $donnee['dcr_38'];           
    $rows6['data'][] = $donnee['dcr_39'];           
    $rows7['data'][] = $donnee['dcr_40'];           
    $rows8['data'][] = $donnee['dcr_41'];           
    $rows9['data'][] = $donnee['dcr_42'];           
    $rows10['data'][] = $donnee['dcr_43'];          
    $rows11['data'][] = $donnee['dcr_44'];          
    $rows12['data'][] = $donnee['dcr_45'];          
    $rows13['data'][] = $donnee['dcr_46'];          
    $rows14['data'][] = $donnee['dcr_47'];          
    $rows15['data'][] = $donnee['dcr_4g'];          

}

$rslt = array(); 

array_push($rslt, $bln);
array_push($rslt, $rows1);
array_push($rslt, $rows2);  
array_push($rslt, $rows3);
array_push($rslt, $rows4);
array_push($rslt, $rows5);
array_push($rslt, $rows6);
array_push($rslt, $rows7);
array_push($rslt, $rows8);
array_push($rslt, $rows9);
array_push($rslt, $rows10);
array_push($rslt, $rows11);
array_push($rslt, $rows12);
array_push($rslt, $rows13);
array_push($rslt, $rows14);
array_push($rslt, $rows15);

print json_encode($rslt, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

$reponse->closeCursor(); 


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem not to have understand how [Highcharts.series](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series) works. I managed to have your code working on a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hfuh3c24/ (Note that I modified a bit the chart options to have the chart rendered clearly on this example)

The important part of the code is where the series array is created : (Suppose that your JSON is parse in the `data_array` variable)

```
var data_array = [/* Your JSON here */];
var series_array = [];
//Starts with 1 and finishes with length - 1 to avoid first and last item
for (var i = 1; i < data_array.length - 1; ++i) {
    series_array.push({
        name: data_array[i].name,
        data: data_array[i].data,
        type: 'column'
    });
}

series_array.push({
    name: data_array[data_array.length - 1].name,
    data: data_array[data_array.length - 1].data,
    type: 'line',
    yAxis: 1
});
```

I hope it will help you to understand better how Highcharts works.

Comment: Thank you so much @Kabulan0lak . I'm not sure though how to use that with my code. My JSON is actually returned by data.php. Do you have any idea how do I integrate it in your piece of code? I added it in my post

Comment: You can use a $.getJSON() to load json from php and then your data_array will be your json from backend.

Comment: Thank you for your help!